# Selective subtotaling in Cognos 10

Tags: grouping, cognos-10

In Cognos 10, when you use groupings and totals in your list, can you just display totals for items grouped, not ALL items in the column? No point in giving the total for just a 1 line item.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going assume that you want to suppress the subtotal row for grouped values that only have one item.

Here's the procedure:

1. Create a new data item to count the number of items within each grouping with the following expression:

   `count(distinct [Item 2] for [Item 1])`
2. Set the Aggregate Function property for the item to 'Calculated'
3. On the report page, select the list object
4. In the properties for the list access the Properties property
5. Check the box corresponding to your new data item and click OK
6. Select a cell within the subtotal row you want to suppress
7. Use the Properties selection arrow to select the List Footer object
8. Add a new Advanced Conditional Style with the following expression:

   `[Count] = 1`
9. Set the style Box Type property to None

Now whenever there is only one item in a grouping, the subtotal row will not be rendered.

You can also use the same technique to reverse the process and hide the detail row and leave the subtotal.